# Remove Cookies Allowed Default EE Message when using Cookie Consent Module

Tags: module, cookies

I have recently installed the Cookie Consent Module on a recent EE site build,
and have added an allow cookies link (ie. {cookies_allowed_link} ) to a policy banner at the top of the site.

My question is:

Is there anyway to remove the default EE ' Cookies Allowed ' grey message box from showing? ie. I just want the user to able to click allow cookies and the site just carries on as normal with out going to a message screen.

Many thanks in advance on this :-)

Regards

Karl

Comment: Please post a snippet of the rendered HTML where this message is being displayed or a URL where this can be seen live. Will help us provide better answers.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If yes, please mark the answer correct by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could:

1. style the systems message template
2. use an addon called custom system messages
3. or look for an AJAX way to do it. the last one is the most elegant, i however, with my limited javascript skills have not yet
       been able to do it

Comment: Hi Jelle many thanks for this. I have actually gone ahead and used the ' Custom System Messages ' third-party module and created a custom template page for now.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this module but if there is a CSS class for the grey message box, you can hide it with CSS using `.classname { display:none }`.

Comment: Hi Anna, yes I may look into the CSS hide option. To be honest though I just don't want the user to leave the page they are on, so I may look further into an AJAX option on this. Many thanks for the feedback :-)

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have got round it by using Jquery to load the page into a new iFrame. I haven't tested it fully though.

I added a click handler to the link with this code:

```
$('a.close-cookie-policy').click(function(){
  var thisLink = $(this).attr('href');

  $('<iframe>', {
    src: thisLink,
    id:  'cookie-frame',
    frameborder: 0,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    scrolling: 'no'
  }).appendTo('body');

  $('.cookie-policy').fadeOut('slow');

  return false;
});
```